# Deploy Laravel Project on Debian Server using Ngnix

Tags: linux, laravel, nginx, debian

So I created an application with laravel, and now I try to host it in a Debian server.

I uploaded all the project laravel found in (/ var / www / html / site)

> (site) is the folder that contains all the files app, public, .env ....

Just that there is also a mybb forum that is running in (/ var / www / html / board) and that's another dev who put it so I do not want to do any wrong manipulation that might make the forum down

So before I look how to start a Laravel project on Debian, and I followed the instructions [from this tutorial](https://blog.here-host.com/install-laravel-debian-9/), (Not all because I had for example already installed, PHP 7.3, phpmyadmin)

> This is how i set ( sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/mydomain.com )

```
    server {
        server_name mydomain.com mydomain.com;
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/html/site/public;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/laravel-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/laravel-error.log;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }    
    }
```

and at the end i run this commund

> sudo service nginx restart

i get this error

```
    root@ns300976:~# sudo service nginx restart
    Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
    See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

> so next i try (systemctl status nginx.service) and i get this

```
    root@ns300976:~# sudo service nginx restart
    Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
    See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
    root@ns300976:~# systemctl status nginx.service
    ● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-11-13 06:37:35 UTC; 40s ago
         Docs: man:nginx(8)
      Process: 21913 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/F
      Process: 21911 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, s
    nov. 13 06:37:33 ns300976 nginx[21913]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, backlog 511 failed (98:
    nov. 13 06:37:34 ns300976 nginx[21913]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (9
    nov. 13 06:37:34 ns300976 nginx[21913]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, backlog 511 failed (98:
    nov. 13 06:37:34 ns300976 nginx[21913]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (9
    nov. 13 06:37:34 ns300976 nginx[21913]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, backlog 511 failed (98:
    nov. 13 06:37:35 ns300976 nginx[21913]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
    nov. 13 06:37:35 ns300976 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
    nov. 13 06:37:35 ns300976 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse pr
    nov. 13 06:37:35 ns300976 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
    nov. 13 06:37:35 ns300976 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    lines 1-17/17 (END)
```

> next i try (journalctl -xe) and i get this

```
    root@ns300976:~# journalctl -xe
    nov. 13 06:59:12 ns300976 sshd[22318]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.89 port 41078 ssh2
    nov. 13 06:59:14 ns300976 sshd[22318]: Failed password for root from 112.85.42.89 port 41078 ssh2
    nov. 13 06:59:15 ns300976 sshd[22318]: Received disconnect from 112.85.42.89 port 41078:11:  [preaut
    nov. 13 06:59:15 ns300`enter code here`976 sshd[22318]: Disconnected from 112.85.42.89 port 41078 [preauth]
    nov. 13 06:59:15 ns300976 sshd[22318]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty
    nov. 13 07:01:01 ns300976 sudo[22331]:     root : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/s
    nov. 13 07:01:01 ns300976 sudo[22331]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by root(
    nov. 13 07:01:01 ns300976 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy ser
    -- Subject: L'unité (unit) nginx.service a commencé à démarrer
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
    --
    -- L'unité (unit) nginx.service a commencé à démarrer.
    nov. 13 07:01:01 ns300976 nginx[22340]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (9
    nov. 13 07:01:01 ns300976 nginx[22340]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, backlog 511 failed (98:
    nov. 13 07:01:02 ns300976 nginx[22340]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (9
    nov. 13 07:01:02 ns300976 nginx[22340]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, backlog 511 failed (98:
    nov. 13 07:01:02 ns300976 nginx[22340]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (9
    nov. 13 07:01:02 ns300976 nginx[22340]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, backlog 511 failed (98:
    nov. 13 07:01:03 ns300976 nginx[22340]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (9
    nov. 13 07:01:03 ns300976 nginx[22340]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, backlog 511 failed (98:
    nov. 13 07:01:03 ns300976 nginx[22340]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (9
    nov. 13 07:01:03 ns300976 nginx[22340]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, backlog 511 failed (98:
    nov. 13 07:01:04 ns300976 nginx[22340]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
    nov. 13 07:01:04 ns300976 sudo[22331]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
    nov. 13 07:01:04 ns300976 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
    nov. 13 07:01:04 ns300976 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse pr
    -- Subject: L'unité (unit) nginx.service a échoué
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
    --
    -- L'unité (unit) nginx.service a échoué, avec le résultat failed.
    nov. 13 07:01:04 ns300976 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
    nov. 13 07:01:04 ns300976 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

this is the first time I have been working with Linux and looking for solutions I have suspected  the apache2 which blocks the port 80

but by doing a kill process, I'm afraid to affect the forum because I do not know if it uses Apache2 for its functions

if I have to run my application via Apache, I would like to have your advice then on this

Thanks for help !

Comment: Test your configuration file like this `nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t`

Answer (score 0):

After root /var/www/html/site/public; add this

```
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
```

I think your apache is running.check this in wchich port which is running

```
sudo netstat -ntpl
```

then kill that process

```
sudo kill pid(your pid)
```